# How to display HTML code as HTML code using PHP

Tags: php

I have the PHP code as below:

```
<?php
  echo "<tr></tr>";
  //ouput I want : <tr></tr>
?>
```

When Output I want to display `<tr></tr>`.But I don know whitch function that I should use for this,anyone know help me please,thanks

Comment: please do home work before you post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try with `htmlentities` like

```
<?php
  echo htmlentities("<tr></tr>");
?>
```

Follow this [**LINK**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Comment: You had earlier put `htmlspecialchars` and now you change it as `htmlentities` , which was previously my answer O.o

Comment: Actually It was just an confusion between...But I have changed within a 10sec.and I have seen your ans after my edit has done

Answer (score 1):

You can also make use of **`htmlentities()`**

```
<?php
  echo htmlentities("<tr></tr>");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$output = htmlspecialchars("<tr></tr>", ENT_QUOTES);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [htmlentities](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
<?php
echo htmlspecialchars('<tr></tr>');
?>
```